# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 when i call MediaMuxer stop

Tags: android, mediamuxer

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. 
my code can run normally on other phones except moto g play
this is the crash log

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 13589
A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'motorola/harpia/harpia:7.1.1/NPIS26.48-43-2/3:user/release-keys'
A/DEBUG: Revision: 'p1b0'
A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
A/DEBUG: pid: 13238, tid: 13589, name: HW264SurfaceEnc  >>> com.tianxingjian.screenshot <<<
A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00003515  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
A/DEBUG:     r4 8567a978  r5 00000006  r6 8567a920  r7 0000010c
A/DEBUG:     r8 00000004  r9 00000000  sl 850a8c60  fp 00000004
A/DEBUG:     ip 0000006e  sp 85679560  lr b5a10407  pc b5a12c64  cpsr 200f0010
A/DEBUG: backtrace:
A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00049c64  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00047403  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0001d555  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000190a1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00017104  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000c72af  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000c6783  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000c53c5  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android11MPEG4Writer5Track12writeCttsBoxEv+184)
A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 000c4c8d  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android11MPEG4Writer5Track12writeStblBoxEb+104)
A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000bfda9  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android11MPEG4Writer5Track16writeTrackHeaderEb+112)
A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 000bf4e3  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android11MPEG4Writer12writeMoovBoxEx+78)
A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 000bdf23  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android11MPEG4Writer5resetEv+1026)
A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 000dd573  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android10MediaMuxer4stopEv+82)
A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 0002adc7  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 73d59985  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x28e2000)
```

this is callback of screen capture, and it will send eos to encoder on stop

```
        @Override
        public void onStart(ScreenCaptureTask task) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "screen capture started");
            mInputSurface = new InputSurface(mSurface);
            mInputSurface.makeCurrent();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop(ScreenCaptureTask task) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "screen capture stopped");
            try {
                mVideoEncoder.signalEOS();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (mAudioCapture != null)
                    mAudioCapture.requestStop();
                stopWriter(STOP_REASON_ERROR_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                report(e, "signal eos error on screen capture stop");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ScreenCaptureTask task, Exception e) {
            Logger.e(TAG, e, "screen capture error");
            mReason = STOP_REASON_ERROR_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
            try {
                mVideoEncoder.signalEOS();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                //
                mVideoTrackIndex = -1;
            }
            report(e, "screen capture error");
            ScreenRecorder.this.onError(new Exception("screen capture error", e));
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(ScreenCaptureTask task, long timeNs) {
            if (mInputSurface != null) {
                mInputSurface.setPresentationTime(timeNs);
                mInputSurface.swapBuffers();
                mVideoEncoder.feed(null, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
```

this is callbak of encoder, will call stopWriter on stop

```
    private class VideoEncoderCallback implements AbsCodec.Callback {
        private long mFirstPts;

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(AbsCodec codec, Surface surface) {
            mSurface = surface;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart(AbsCodec codec) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "video encoder started");
            if (mVideoCapture != null) {
                MCInfo mcInfo = mVideoEncoder.getMCInfo();
                if (mcInfo != null && mcInfo.mediaFormat != null) {
                    mVideoCapture.setSize(mcInfo.mediaFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH),
                            mcInfo.mediaFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT));
                }
                mVideoCapture.requestStart();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop(AbsCodec codec) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "video encoder stopped");
            stopWriter(mReason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(AbsCodec codec, Exception e) {
            Logger.e(TAG, e, "video encoder error");
            mReason = STOP_REASON_ERROR_VIDEO_ENCODE;
            if (mVideoCapture != null) {
                mVideoCapture.requestStop();
                mVideoCapture = null;
            }
            if (mAudioCapture != null) {
                mAudioCapture.requestStop();
                mAudioCapture = null;
            }
            ScreenRecorder.this.onError(new Exception("video encoder error", e));
            report(e, "video encoder error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onOutputFormatChanged(AbsCodec codec, MediaFormat outputFormat) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "video encoder output format changed, %s", outputFormat);
            startWriter(outputFormat, null);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOutputBufferAvailable(AbsCodec codec, ByteBuffer buffer, MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo) {
            synchronized (mWriterStartLock) {
                if (!mWriterStarted) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (mFirstPts == 0)
                mFirstPts = bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs;
            bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs -= mFirstPts;
            onTimelineChanged(bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs);
            return writeSampleData(false, buffer, bufferInfo);
        }
    }
```

```
    void stopWriter(int reason) {
        if ((reason & STOP_REASON_STOP_REQUEST_SAW_EOS) == 0) {
            mVideoTrackIndex = -1;
            mAudioTrackIndex = -1;
        }
        Logger.i(TAG, "stop writer " + mVideoTrackIndex + ", " + mAudioTrackIndex);
        if (mVideoTrackIndex >= 0 || mAudioTrackIndex >= 0) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "wait all track stop");
            return;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mWriter.stop();
            mWriter.release();
            Logger.d(TAG, "writer stopped, reason %d", reason);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Logger.e(TAG, e, "stop writer error, reason %d", reason);
            report(e, "stop writer error, reason %d", reason);
            if (mCallback != null)
                mCallback.onError(this, new Exception("stop writer error, reason " + reason, e));
            return;
        } finally {
            synchronized (mWriterStartLock) {
                mWriterStarted = false;
            }
        }
        onStop((reason & STOP_REASON_ERROR) == 0);
    }
```

```
    public void stop() {
        if (mState != MUXER_STATE_STARTED) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Can't stop due to wrong state.");
        }
        if (mUseBuiltin) {
            mBuiltinWriter.stop(); // this is MediaMuxer
        } else {
            mWriter.stop();
        }
    }


    public void release() {
        if (mState == MUXER_STATE_STARTED) {
            stop();
        }
        if (mWriter != null) {
            mWriter.release();
            mWriter = null;
        }
        if (mBuiltinWriter != null) {
            mBuiltinWriter.release();
            mBuiltinWriter = null;
        }
        mState = MUXER_STATE_UNINITIALIZED;
    }
```

i have been search days for this, but can not fix it, please help me

Comment: Please post some code... 
Logs alone wont help

Comment: I have post some code

Comment: I dont see any code

Comment: sorry, i post code as answer, but has been deleted, i edit my question now